# submitting forms in vuejs, should I use the form tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm so confused how I should submit and handle edit forms in vuejs.

How I'm doing it now is I have a component called TreeForm.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-text-field v-model="cloned_tree.root" />
    <v-text-field v-model="cloned_tree.root" />
    <v-file-input type="number" v-model="cloned_tree.fruits" />
    <v-btn @click="$emit('save', {idx: tree_idx, tree: cloned_tree})">Save</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {tree_idx: Number},
    data() {
      return {
        cloned_tree: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.trees[this.tree_idx])),
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

And in the parent component I do:

```
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <TreeForm tree_idx="0" @save="submitTreeForm" />
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapActions} from 'vuex';
  export default {
    methods: {
      ...mapActions(['submitTreeForm']),
    },
  };
</script>
```

And in my vuex I do:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.mydomain.com/api',
  timeout: 10000,
  withCredentials: true,
});
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state: {
    trees: [
      {
        root: 'hello',
        imageFile: require('some/picture'),
        fruits: 5,
      },
    ],
  },
  mutations: {
    updateTree(state, payload) {
      state.trees[payload.idx] = payload.tree;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    submitVideoForm({commit}, payload) {
      api
        .post('/trees/update/', payload)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.success == 1) {
            commit('updateTree', payload);
          } else {
            console.log(response.data.success);
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
});
```

But I feel like This is not the correct way to do it specially because I'm not using `<v-form>` or `<form>` tags. I also haven't incorporated validation yet, I'm thinking of using vuelidate. So please give me the best practice for submitting and handling edit form while validation is done by vuelidate.

Comment: The Vue Material page have a Form's example, I think that can help you: https://vuematerial.io/components/form. You can look the implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, the `form` tag is not mandatory. Unless using some kind of CSS framework, the UI will look the same with or without the `form` tag. But, it still has some pros:

Ben Nadel put it best in his blog [post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2435-are-html-form-tags-required-to-display-form-input-controls.htm):

> ... it seems that using a FORM tag does have some benefits, depending
>   on your particular situation:
>
> - You need it if you want to execute a traditional (ie. non-AJAX) form
>     post.
> - You need it you want to capture the "submit" event
>     programmatically.
> - You need it in order for mobile Safari to show the
>     "Go" button on the keyboard.
> - You need it if you want to
>     programmatically "reset" a form (ie. call reset()).
> - It makes generic
>     form serialization easier (since it groups input fields).
> - You need it if you want to post files without the modern file API.
> - You need it if you have to segregate fields with the same name.

Vue.js gets you covered in almost all these situations. But if it doesn't - use form.

Comment: If you want to go by the book, then add the form tag.